# How to solve $\int\left[(x^2-1)(x+1)\right]^{-2/3}dx$ with $u=\arctan x$

Tags: calculus

I was asked to solve  $$\int\left[(x^2-1)(x+1)\right]^{-2/3}dx$$ with $u=\arctan x$. Since $du=\frac{1}{1+x^2}dx$, I transformed the oringinal expression into $$\int\left[(x^2-1)(x+1)\right]^{-2/3}(1+x^2)du.$$
Then since $x=\tan u$, I got $$\int\left[\left(\sin^{2}u-\cos^{2}u\right)(\sin u+\cos u)\right]^{-2/3}du$$ after some simplifications. But I don't know what to do next. Transforming the expression into $$\int(\sin u-\cos u)^{-2/3}(\sin u+\cos u)^{-4/3}du$$ seems unhelpful.

Comment: [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint+%28%28x%5E2-1%29*%28x%2B1%29%29%5E%28-2%2F3%29+dx) step-by-step shows $u=\frac{1}{x+1}$ leads to $-\int \frac{1}{(1-2u)^{2/3}}\,\mathrm{d}u$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note

$$(\frac{\sin u+\cos u}{\sin u-\cos u})'=\frac{-2}{(\sin u-\cos u)^2}$$

Thus

\begin{align*}
I&=\int (\sin u-\cos u)^{-2/3}(\sin u+\cos u)^{-4/3}\,du \\
&=\int (\sin u-\cos u)^{-2}(\sin u-\cos u)^{4/3}(\sin u+\cos u)^{-4/3} \,du \\
&=-\frac{1}{2} \int (\frac{\sin u+\cos u}{\sin u-\cos u})^{-4/3}\,d(\frac{\sin u+\cos u}{\sin u-\cos u}) \\
&=\frac{3}{2}(\frac{\sin u+\cos u}{\sin u-\cos u})^{-1/3}+C
\end{align*}

Comment: Actually,you have to use u=arctan(x).That's the point of this question.

Comment: @AJoke Ok,let me think about it